# How to upgrade processmaker from version 4.1 to 4.2.30

Tags: processmaker

I want upgrade **ProcessMaker** version 4.1 to the latest version. How can I do it?
I have already installed version 4.1 and I want to update to the latest current version, 4.2.30.
Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ProcessMaker/processmaker/tree/v4.2.31 you should be able to upgrade it just like any laravel application through db migrations etc